# How to use "Update-in" in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use Clojure's update-in function but I can't seem to understand why I need to pass in a function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`update-in` takes a function, so you can update a value at a given position depending on the old value more concisely. For example instead of:

```
(assoc-in m [list of keys] (inc (get-in m [list of keys])))
```

you can write:

```
(update-in m [list of keys] inc)
```

Of course if the new value does not depend on the old value, `assoc-in` is sufficient and you don't need to use `update-in`.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but one reason why a function like `update-in` could exist would be for efficiency—not just convenience—if it were able to update the value in the map "in-place". That is, rather than

- seeking the key in the map,
- finding the corresponding key-value tuple,
- extracting the value,
- computing a new value based on the current value,
- seeking the key in the map,
- finding the corresponding key-value tuple,
- and overwriting the value in the tuple or replacing the tuple with a new one

one can instead imagine an algorithm that would omit the second search for the key:

- seek the key in the map,
- find the corresponding key-value tuple,
- extract the value,
- compute a new value based on the current value,
- and overwrite the value in the tuple

Unfortunately, [the current implementation of `update-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in) does not do this "in-place" update. It uses [`get`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get) for the extraction and [`assoc`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc) for the replacement. Unless `assoc` is using some caching of the last looked up key and the corresponding key-value tuple, the call to `assoc` winds up having to seek the key again.

Comment: You make it sound as if the only difference between your in-place variant and the actual implementation is that the in-place variant only looks up the keys once (which implies that `update-in` could be changed in later versions of clojure to use your in-place variant without breaking any existing code). However a much more important difference is that the in-place variant would necessarily have to mutate the map, while `update-in` does not (and, given that mutating methods usually have a `!` in their name, should not).

Comment: Well, even a non-destructive version could take advantage of knowing the "hit" position; even `assoc` needs to figure which part of the original map it's *not* going to copy and instead provide the updated value.

Comment: Nice, +1 for a concrete performance improvement suggestion to the core Clojure library!

Comment: I wouldn't call this an improvement--I would call it fixing a bug.

Also, redeeming is the fact that the extra lookup only occurs at the leaf update in the tree of keys. That is, the extraneous call to (get) does not restart from the root node of the search, only at the level of the very last one.

Comment: @andrewcooke Good algorithms are relevant in any language.

Comment: i agree.  maybe you've never heard of the phrase "lisp weenie"?  or maybe only i see the irony.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment is incorrect: the double lookup hit is taken at every level.

Answer (score 4):

I think the short answer is that the function passed to update-in lets you update values in a single step, rather than 3 (lookup, calculate new value, set).

Coincidentally, just today I ran across this use of update-in in a Clojure presentation by Howard Lewis Ship:

```
(def in-str "this is this")
(reduce 
  (fn [m k] (update-in m [k] #(inc (or % 0)))) 
  {} 
  (seq in-str))

==> {\space 2, \s 3, \i 3, \h 2, \t 2}
```

Each call to update-in takes a letter as a key, looks it up in the map, and if it's found there increments the letter count (else sets it to 1). The reduce drives the process by starting with an empty map {} and repeatedly applies the update-in with successive characters from the input string. The result is a map of letter frequencies. Slick.

Note 1: clojure.core/frequencies is similar but uses assoc! rather than update-in.

Note 2: You can replace #(inc (or % 0)) with (fnil inc 0).  From here: [fnil](http://java.dzone.com/articles/clojure-fnil?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+javalobby%2Ffrontpage+%28Javalobby+%2F+Java+Zone%29)

Comment: Markc this is an amazing pattern ! Whenever you want to create a new type of seq after processing the current seq ( in the above case a map from a str) use reduce ! Thanks for illustrating it.

Answer (score 2):

A practical example you see [here](https://github.com/paulosuzart/xstandard/blob/master/src/xstandard/core.clj#L132).

Type this snippet (in your REPL):

```
(def my-map {:useless-key "key"})
;;{:useless-key "key"}
(def my-map (update-in my-map [:yourkey] #(cons 1 %)))
;;{:yourkey (1), :useless-key "key"}
```

Note that `:yourkey` is new. So the value - of `:yourkey` - passed to the lambda is `null`. `cons` will put `1` as the single element of your list. Now do the following:

```
(def my-map (update-in my-map [:yourkey] #(cons 25 %)))
;;{:yourkey (25 1), :useless-key "key"}
```

And that is it, in the second part, the anonymous function takes the list - the value for :yourkey - as argument and just cons 25 to it.

Since our `my-map` is immutable, `update-in` will always return a new version of your map letting you do something with the old value of the given key.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I was a little confused by this example I have to admit.

Comment: what is the doubt? useless-key is there just to show the advantage of update-in: You can "walk" through nested levels in you map and put a value returned by a function that takes the old value - if any - as argument. The result of that function is the new entry value. A new map with the new value is returned for each update-in invokation, that is why the example always def my-map, a reassignment allowed in REPL.